# Monitor not working | VGA | Windows 8

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, vga, dvi

Today I received my configured PC I bought off a supplier.
I am using Dual screens and they are both VGA. One is gone into my VGA port and the other into my graphics cards DVI port (i used converter to turn the VGA into DVI).

The DVI that is feeded into my graphics card works but the VGA cabled monitor is not working. I open screen resolution and click "Detect" to try and find the second monitor but have no luck. The monitors are 100% working and functional.

I am using:

- Windows 8
- Geforce GTX 960
- Asus motherboard

I have tried:

- Installing and updating graphics card driver
- Updated Syncmaster driver

It is a fresh system so they may well be something I need to install to get it working?

Sorry if i missed any information out, please let me know and i can inform you.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: First guess would be that either the GPU output or the converter is DVI-D, not DVI-A… therefore, no analog output for VGA